# Convert numbers into strings while leaving characters untouched in R

Tags: r

I have a vector that looks like this:

```
> vector <- c("1","2","0", "10", "name", "hello")
```

I want to convert it so that each numeric character becomes a string, leaving actual strings unaffected.

```
[1] "test" "test" "test" "test" "name" "hello"
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sub("^\\d+$", "test", vector)
[1] "test"  "test"  "test"  "test"  "name"  "hello"

str_replace(vector, "^[0-9]+$", "test")
[1] "test"  "test"  "test"  "test"  "name"  "hello"
```

Answer (score 3):

One option with `warnings` is to convert to `integer` and check for `NA` values with `is.na` and do the assignment

```
vector[!is.na(as.integer(vector))] <- "test"
```

-output

```
> vector
[1] "test"  "test"  "test"  "test"  "name"  "hello"
```

The idea is that non-NA elements returns NA when convert to numeric and this is captured as a logical vector with `is.na` to subset the original vector and then do the assignment

---

Another option without warnings is also possible with a regex i.e. find the elements where there are only digits or dot from the start (`^`) to the end (`$`) and replace those with 'test'

```
vector[grep("^[0-9.]+$", vector)] <- "test"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
library(stringr)

str_replace_all(vector, "[0-9].*", 'test')
```

```
[1] "test"  "test"  "test"  "test"  "name"  "hello"
```